# Can I push a git repository that includes a symbolic link?

Tags: git, push, symlink

My git directory structure is the following:

```
content/
config.js
symDir # this is a symbolic link to another directory in the filesystem
```

However, I would like to push this git repository to a cloud environment, and pull the pushed git repository from within another machine.

Actually, I tried it, but then the pulled directory is something like the following:

```
content/
config.js
symDir~9e150f782ca9f6595225471be5823015618bef47
```

The symbolic link object just points to another filesystem, but the filesystem is on the different machine (the machine that pushed it), and would no longer be available.

That being said, I would like to push directory as a symbolic link; I would not like to bother to deleting and adding the whole directory to the git repository whenever I make a change, in order to just push it.

Is it possible or is there any workaround to push a git repository that has a symbolic link and use it from within another machine?

Comment: Git handles symbolic links just fine, as symbolic links, *provided* your OS and file system allow them. (Windows does not except via NTFS.)

Comment: @torek So is there any workaround to this..?

Comment: Mine would be "don't use Windows". I have no idea if there is one that *does* use Windows...

Comment: @torek A machine that pushes the repository is Mac, and one that pulls is Ubuntu on Google Compute Engine. But the Ubuntu machine doesn't have the linked directory in its filesystem.

Comment: Wait ... are you saying that you want the *contents* of the *target* of the symlink to somehow appear magically on the other machine, without ever sending those contents? That's not going to work. A symlink is just a file containing the name of a file: that's all it is and all Git does with it.

Comment: @torek I meant, if there is any workaround in git, such as track the linked repository and copy it whenever the contents are changed, etc...

Comment: The target of a symlink is not necessarily a repository. Git *does* have a way to say "repository X uses repository Y": that's called a *submodule*. Submodules are not symbolic links.